# Calling things in <script> or using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, babylonjs

I've been looking at a lot of different tutorials learning about the coding that I have been doing, and I've noticed one common difference. Basically, some people use HTML purely to write scripts, using the script tag, and some people use JavaScript and reference the script. My problem lies in two codes. The first one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='babylon.js'></script>
        <title>game or some shit</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            .canvas {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='gamecanvas'></canvas>
        <script>
            var BABYLON;
            var canvas = document.getElementById('gamecanvas');
            var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
            var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
            var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera('camera', 1,2,20, new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0), scene);
            var light = new BABYLON.PointLight('light', new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,10), scene);
            var ball = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere('ball', 10, 1.0, scene);

            scene.activeCamera.attachControl(canvas);
            engine.runRenderLoop(function()
            {
                scene.render();
            });
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Functions properly, but when I reference it in a script using an external script like this:

```
var BABYLON;
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera('camera', 1,2,20, new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0), scene);
var light = new BABYLON.PointLight('light', new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,10), scene);
var ball = new BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere('ball', 10, 1.0, scene);

function INIT_GAME()
{
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    scene.activeCamera.attachControl(canvas);
    engine.runRenderLoop(function()
    {
        scene.render();
    });
}
```

and call it in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='jquery2.2.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='game.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery.js'></script>
        <script src='babylon.js'></script>
        <title>beta af lmaoo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            .background {
                position: absolute;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }
            .start {
                position:absolute;
                bottom:21%;
                right:40%;
            }
            .canvas {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='gameCanvas'></canvas>
        <menu>
            <img class='background' src='Images/backgroundImg.jpg'/>
            <embed src='Audio/backgroundMusic.mp3' autoplay='true' loop='true' width='0' height='0'/>
            <input class='start' type='image' src='Images/start.jpg' width='275' height='150' onclick='INIT_GAME();'/>
        </menu>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't function. Can anyone tell me why the script won't work when I type it externally in another JavaScript file and call it, but it will in vanilla HTML? Also, which do you prefer to use? Is using `<script>` better or using a JavaScript file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misidentified the problem. This has nothing to do with moving the script from inline to an external file.

You've also (and more significantly) moved the script element from below `gameCanvas` to above it.

Now, when you say `var canvas = document.getElementById('gamecanvas');` you get `null` (because the element doesn't exist yet).

(It also looks like you've moved it to before babylon.js, so you'll also error because `BABYLON.Engine` won't yet exist either).

Comment: So to fix it, you could move the file reference to the body. I guess you could wait til the dom is loaded as well.

Comment: So, order matters. Good to know. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

To extend what @Quentin mentioned.

```
<script src='jquery2.2.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='game.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='babylon.js'></script>
```

Where these script tags are placed is important, and so is the order. When they are in 'HEAD' they will be executed very early in the rendering process. Your HTML is rendered top-down and each script is executed when they are called. If you do not want to worry about the DOM (everything inside the `BODY` tag) not being ready you will want to place all the script tags at the bottom of your HTML `BODY` right before the closing `</body>`. Additionally if they do not function correctly at that point make sure they are in order. From your original content the above list is **NOT** correct as you need to have babylon.js before game.js most likely.

Also as a side note: don't import jQuery more than once as that can be problematic.

Comment: To clarify, I didn't import jQuery twice, the file is just named jQuery. Thanks for the info!

Comment: So I know it is not a big deal, but named 'jQuery' I would recommend against that incase you introduce names AMD modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I load my JavaScript...

FROM THE HTML:

The include:

```
<script src="http://js.awwshop.com/render/pub/shkawn/shkawn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The call:

```
<body onload="Init.Load();">
```

THE LOADER CLASS

```
var Init = new function () {


// POPUP IMAGE SCRIPT
document.write("<script src='http://js.awwshop.com/render/pub/shared/parse.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
document.write("<script src='http://js.awwshop.com/render/pub/shared/popup-image.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");

// GO TO URL SCRIPT
document.write("<script src='http://js.awwshop.com/render/pub/shared/go-to-url.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");


this.Load = function () {


    PopupImage.LoadPopupImages("http://img.awwshop.com/render/pub/shkawn/progressbar.gif");


}
```

}

Also, I use classes for all my stuff. That means that each of those files referenced includes/all-it-is-is a class.

I've never run into null reference errors doing it this way.

Comment: I'm not generally very organized, I should probably get into that habit. Thanks!